# Как просмотреть исходный код стандарнтного модуля Python?

Tags: python

надо заливать с Git?
или как-то можно после import ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Вариант 1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource):

```
import inspect
import your_module
print(inspect.getsource(your_module)) # не будет работать для части built-in модулей
```

Вариант 2, если нужны [исходники самого СPythona](https://github.com/python/cpython):

```
git clone https://github.com/python/cpython.git
```

И уже рыться в Сишных исходниках

Вариант 3
Есть замечательная команда help()

```
help(your_module) # если нужно не сам исходный код модуль, а пример использования, подсказка
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно Но работает не для всех модулей.

```
import module
print('Путь к файлу:', module.__file__)
```

Comment: для heapq сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Если модуль на питоне, то он лежит в папке Lib установленного питона, но часть модулей на С.

Питоновские модули, естественно, доступны во всех отладчиках, можно просто в отладке войти внутрь и смотреть код по мере выполнения.